# Remove multiple query string parameters from htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've got a problem with some website URLs which I want htaccess to redirect after removing a few query string parameters, for example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?s=200&dis=default&opt=foo
http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?dis=foo&opt=baz
```

or

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?type=default&format=rss
http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?pg=3&format=rss&type=default
```

I want to save all the parameters except for `type`, `format`, `dis` or `opt` which are causing a 404 error. I've found a way to remove a single parameter, but I still can't find a regex or something to remove multiple query parameters.

This is my code so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/archive
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?view=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?opt=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?type=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?format=[^&]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Which doesn't work because it removes just a single parameter and saves the others that are causing errors.

P.S. As you can see, it should work only on 'archive' page, but that's not a problem :)

## UPDATE

This is an URL that I'm testing at the moment:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?foo=0&force=0&format=feed&type=rss
```

Which I want to be like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?foo=0&force=0
```

## RE-UPDATED

By using collapsar's answer, the server's `error_log` shows this:

```
Invalid command '<If', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: According to the docs, query strings are excluded from being rewritten by default - didn't remember this one. However, there are processing Flags that can dealwith it. I am updating the answer.

Comment: FYI: You alternately name `dis` and `view` in your list of offending parameter names.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was just a mistyping

Answer (score 0):

**Discussion**

Unfortunately, the query string portion of urls is excluded from rewriting by default. the `RewriteRule` directive does not match against the query string portion. Any Query string needs to be appended expressly in the substitution string.

This implies that the rewriting cannot be accomplished without resorting to `RewriteCond` directives ( fwiw, that is why the previous versions of this answer have been wrong ).

`RewriteRule` performs the actual rewriting after *any one* of `RewriteCond` patterns linked with the `OR` flag matches. This implies that the set of conditions will not be exhaustively tested.

**Solution**

Adjust your rule set as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/archive
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)([&?])format=[^&]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1%2%3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/archive
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)([&?])opt=[^&]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1%2%3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/archive
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)([&?])type=[^&]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1%2%3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/archive
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)([&?])view=[^&]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1%2%3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/archive
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[?])breaktheloop=1(.*)$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?breaktheloop=1 [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1%2 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` patterns take into account that improperly escaped urls may be the value of some parameter in the query string. Drop the non-greedy matching modifier (ie. use `^(.*)` instead of `^(.*?)`) if you are not concerned about this.

**Synopsis**

The differences to the OP's original solution are:

- individual substitution of each offending parameter
- including the parameter separator in the substitution pattern
- catering for improperly escaped urls as a parameter value
- individual rewriting (copy) rule to trigger redirection after any number of substitutions have applied. `QSA` flag is necessary to keep the sanitized query string.
- `breaktheloop` parameter to, well, break the redirection loop.

**Documentation**

The respective section of the [Apache httpd directive docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) is the place to find more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please see the updated question? RewriteRule gives error 500

Comment: You've adopted the wrong `RewiteRule` - and my `RewriteRule`s have been syntactically wrong. The curse of c&p ... Please see the updated answer. Note that the backreferences to `RewriteCond` matches ( `%...` ) do not make sense with my solution.

Comment: I'm using your first ´RewriteRule´, but it's not redirecting. I updated my question with an URL which I'm testing. Sorry, maybe I'm not clear enough or I'm just missing something from your answer

Comment: Ok. The tests on Regex 101 pass. Please 1) check that you have set `RewriteEngine on`, 2) check that no more `RewriteRule`s follow (since you dropped the `L` flag) 3) enclose the arguments to `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule` in double quotes ( eg. `RewriteRule "([&?])(option|format|type|view)=[^&]+" "$1" [R=301]` ).

Comment: Still not working. I'm testing them on Regex101 too and even with Notepad++ find/replace, and it works. But it doesn't on browser, even if there's a `RewriteEngine on` before, no more `RewriteRule`s after it and by enclosing rules in double quotes

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong. You're trying to redirect each time the query string contains one of the unwanted parameters by removing them one-by-one, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm _replacing_ each offending parameter individually, the redirection is supposed to happen only once. However, your comment made me notice that the logic would work out only if the last test actually matched. Arrgh, I'm rustier with Apache configs than I thought I'd be.

Comment: So, your last code actually replaces query string as it should be, so, thank you, really. However, there's still a little problem... it creates a redirect loop. I'm going to buy you some beers after this

Comment: See the updated answer. The synthetic `breaktheloop` parameter triggers  the new first rule which deletes that parameter from the query string and which carries the `L` flag, so rewriting will stop here.

Comment: I've read the docs, and I found the `breaktheloop` parameter too. The problem is that when I try your `RewriteCond`s, it goes in a `breaktheloop` loop, and the url becomes `http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?breaktheloop=1&breaktheloop=1&breaktheloop=1`. Sorry man, this is such annoying...

Comment: Seems that insetad of the `L flag in the first ruleblock one should use `END`.` Answer adjusted.

Comment: `END` might prevent further necessary processing steps. I have replaced its use by directives for explicit control flow.

Comment: I've found an online htaccess tester which tests my url and says that I should be redirected to `http://www.mywebsite.com/archive?breaktheloop=1` which is actually right, but my browser keeps on giving 500 error

Comment: Do your logs contain a more detailed error message?

Comment: You are using http code 301 (permanent redirect) for the redirection - could it be that - after all the trial & e ... er testing - somewhere in the processing pipeline an obsolete url has been cached ? Have you tried 302/307 (temporary redirect) ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the error retrieved from server's logs. Using temporary redirects still giving 500 error

Comment: What is the Apache version you are running?

Comment: I've changed the ruleset to be compatible with Apache 2.2.

Comment: Still loops on `?breaktheloop=1&breaktheloop=1&...`

Comment: Are you using authentication for the website in question ?

Comment: It's a Joomla site, the only authentication is the one which let you use the Joomla's backoffice